# is infinite number of searches possible in office JS?

Tags: javascript, office-js

A new problem has emerged with this functionality.  Office.js seems to have some limitation (or memory leak  with the number of API call you can make in a chain of calls.  Seems to be around 40-50 calls before it blows up.

for Example if i call this function in a loop for 20 to 30 times it works however if more than  40-50 times its breaks and throws unhandled Promise exception which when tracked brings me back to office inside so i am wandering if infinite number of body.search() in word.run is possible word

```js
export function searchInBody(input, onSuccess) {
    const { Word } = window;
    Word.run(context => {
        const { body } = context.document;
        const searchResults = body.search(input.substring(0, 255), { matchCase: false });
        context.load(searchResults, 'text, font');
        return context.sync().then(() => onSuccess(searchResults));
    });
}
```